# Prononciation : [i] au lieu de [y]

Tags: prononciation

J'ai entendu plusieurs fois des francophones originaires d'Afrique du nord prononcer le son [i] au lieu du son [y]. Par exemple :
Lic (pour Luc), Jési (pour Jésus), isine (pour usine) etc.

Comment s'appelle ce phénomène et d'où provient-il ?

Comment: Probablement [des éléments de réponses](https://hal-auf.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01411661/document).

Comment: "J'ai entendu", non?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ceci ne traite pas la question exactement puisque sont concernés non pas les Noirs de France mais les arabes de France. Néanmoins, le phénomène linguistique est le même, en résultat, sinon très possiblement sur le plan de son explication , et il semble très intéressant de le rapporter dans un contexte plus étendu de la question. Il doit s'agir pour le cas de la prononciation du français par les arabes, d'un phénomène d'absence du son composé « [y] » dans la langue arabe et d'une implémentation donc de cette voyelle manquante par  la voyelle simple non-labialisée qui correspond  (on passe du [i] au [y] par un simple arrondissement des lèvres (labialisé) sans changer autre chose (place d'articulation, place de la langue)).   Cet [article](https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_1973_num_19_1_5642)  donne l'explication.

[image]

p. 104  L'apprentissage du français chez les Arabophones maghrébins (diglossie et plurilinguisme en Tunisie) J.-L. Maume

Note : Aucune information similaire ne semble disponible en ce qui concerne la prononciation des Africains noirs de France.

Note : La présente réponse ne se comprend que selon la question du PO avant que celle-ci soit corrigée. Il n'est toujours pas certain après cette correction si le PO voulait dire "afro-français" (catégorie qui n'inclut pas les arabes et signifie seulement « individu d'Afrique Noire »))